# Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ open, $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $i$ times differentiable in $x\in U$...

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ open, $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $i$ times differentiable in $x\in U$, $f(U)\subset V$, and $g:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$ $i$ times differentiable in $y=f(x)$. for each partition $i=i_1+i_2+...+i_k$ with $i_i,i_2,..$ natural numbers, exists $M(i_1,i_2,..,i_k) \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that the i-th derived of $g\circ f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$ is $$(g\circ f)^{(i)}=\sum_{k=1}^{i}M(i_1,i_2,..,i_k)g^{(k)}\circ f.(f^{(i_1)},...,f^{(i_k)}) $$
all suggestions are welcome

I'm trying to prove by induction on $i$. Give a partition of $i+1=i_1,i_2,..,i_j$, suppose $i_j>1$ then $i=i_1,i_2,..,(i_j-1)$ is partition of $i$  $$(g\circ f)^{(i)}=\sum_{j=1}^{i}M(i_1,i_2,..,i_j-1)g^{(j)}\circ f.(f^{(i_1)},...,f^{(i_j-1)}) $$
then is suffice derive the above? Here I get stuck.